# cumulative sum using array.fold in F#

Tags: f#

I have an array of the following type

```
let myarray = [| 1 .. 5 |]
```

I would like to get another array where each element is a cumulative sum of elements that come before it:

```
let mycumarray = [| 1 3 6.. 15 |]
```

What I tried to do is:

```
let sumArray array = Array.fold (fun acc elem -> acc + elem) 0.0 array
let mycumarray = sumArray myarray
```

However it does not work. Does anybody have any suggestions to obtain a cumulative sum?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you're looking for `Array.scan`, which is very similar to `Array.fold`, but returns all the state values instead of just the final one:

```
(Array.scan (+) 0 myArray).[1..]
```

The `.[1..]` is array slicer notation ([see the MSDN on arrays in F#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233214.aspx)) to drop the first element, which is necessary because `scan` includes the initial state in the output.

Comment: Instead of 0 one can to take the first element of the array:                                                                                                         Array.scan (+) myArray.[0] myArray                                                            But then need to know that the array is not empty

Comment: @FoggyFinder this doesn't yield the correct result, as the first entry is added twice. It could be `Array.scan (+) myArray.[0] myArray.[1..]`. Anyway, any version using the `.[1..]` slicer will fail with an `IndexOutOfRangeException` on empty arrays, so this should be checked if it is a possible case.

Comment: Oh, of course. I hurried. Thank that you corrected my answer

Answer (score 1):

`Array.scan` is surely the best solution but you can use your `fold` if you want like this:

```
let cumList xs = 
    List.ofSeq xs 
    |> List.fold (fun (acc, ys) elem -> 
                      let acc' = acc + elem 
                      in (acc', ys @ [acc'])) 
       (0, []) 
    |> snd 
    |> List.toArray
```

here is your example:

```
> cumList [|1..5|];;                                                                                                                               
val it : int [] = [|1; 3; 6; 10; 15|]
```

Note that the `@` is not optimal but it shows nicely what is done (if performance is important you can use `List.foldBack` or do `::` in there and a final `List.rev` to get the right ordering.

Also you could use `Array.append` directly instead of `@`

### making the example generic on numbers:

```
let inline cumList xs = 
    List.ofSeq xs 
    |> List.fold (fun (acc, ys) elem -> 
                      let acc' = acc + elem 
                      in (acc', ys @ [acc'])) 
       (LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero, []) 
    |> snd 
    |> List.toArray
```

you see you just have to make the function `inline` and use `GenericZero` instead of `0` (which is assumed to be an `int`)

btw: this works too with the `Array.scan` approach:

```
let inline cumList2 xs =
    Array.scan (+) LanguagePrimitives.GenericOne xs
```

**remark** the array-slice is unnecessary in this case if you just start with `1` instead of `0`!

Comment: Carsten, thanks for your answer. How about if my list is float, how would I edit the above code for: cumList [|1.0..5.0|]?

Comment: you would just change the `(0,[])` into `(0.0,[])` or you can make it *generic*  for numbers - I'll add this